Sidebar with vertical scroll that contains drag and drop items that are not visible outside
I have a sidebar with some divs that overflow the height and so vertical scrollbar is needed.
The problem it's that these divs can be drag and dropped outside the sidebar.
So the sidebar must have the overflow property to visible in order to let the divs appears outside, but with overflow visible the vertical scrollbar disappear...
Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4p6m72js/
If you set overflow-y: visible at line 15 in css, the vertical scrollbar disappear and the divs overflows, but when you drag and drop one div outside the sidebar works well.
I'm using the library InteractJS for drag and drop feature.
